# Trix validation of URL using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string, trix

I am trying to alter the pattern of the validation to accept these starts

```
https://
http://
https://www.
http://www. 
www.
```

This is what I have now:

```
inputElement.pattern = '^(https:?//|http:?//|http:?//www|https:?//www|www).+$';
```

It accept faulty cases such as :

```
wwwsa.se
http://ww.
```

got to this point using https://github.com/basecamp/trix/issues/624

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
^(?:(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?w{3})(?:[.].*|)|(?:https?:?\/\/(?!w{1,2}\.).*))$
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/DxplGp/5/)

```js
const regex = /^(?:(?:(?:https?:\/\/)?w{3})(?:[.].*|)|(?:https?:?\/\/(?!w{1,2}\.).*))$/i;
const arr = ['https://','http://','https://www.','http://www.','www.','wwwsa.se','http://ww.','http://www.','ww.','www.','www//','www.g', 'http://wix']

arr.forEach(str => {
  console.log(str, '\t\t' ,regex.test(str))
})
```

Comment: There is no need to check for `www` after `http://` and `https://` since according to description if string starts from `http://` or `https://` it's already valid.

Comment: That is very true. Since websites can have wwwwws.com or something.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need something like `^(http(s)?://)|(www\.)`

Comment: I get this for the "\." 38:60  error  Unnecessary escape character: \.  no-useless-escape

and "www.test.se" does not work

Comment: Are you sure you're using it correctly, i've just tried `(/^(http(s)?:\/\/)|(www\.)/).test('www.test.se')` and it returns `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

```
  element.pattern = '^((\\/)|(https?:\\/\\/)|mailto:).*$'
```

It allows for
relative urls (beginning with a /),
urls beginning https:// or http://, and mailto links